# useState set method for modal not updating

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to build a simple todo list. Basically there is a list of items. When the user clicks the 'edit' button on an item, `selectedTodoItem` is updated. Then a modal is shown which uses `selectedTodoItem` as prop.
I am also using [ant.design library](https://ant.design/components/list/) for the list.
Here is my code (with irrelevant bits left out):

```js
const [selectedTodoItem, setSelectedTodoItem] = useState(selectedTodoList.items[0]);

const editItemHandler = (item) => {
    setSelectedTodoItem(item);
    dispatch(toggleEditTodoItemModalVisible());
}

return(
    <List
    className="whitebg listItems"
    datasource={selectedTodoList.items}
    renderItem={(item) => (
        <TodoItemInList item={item} editHandler={editItemHandler} />
    )}
    />
    <TodoItemEditModal item={selectedTodoItem} />
);
```

`<TodoItemInList>` is basically a label and some buttons, one of which calls `editHandler(item)`.
Here's a screenshot so you can get a better idea:

[image]

The problem is, when I load the page and click edit (blue, don't mind the delete icon) on an item, say 'Foundation', the edit modal loads fine. But when I click on another blue button, the modal still shows 'Foundation'. No matter what button I click, the modal only shows the first clicked item. It seems like `selectedTodoItem` is updating though, according to console.log(), but the modal's prop doesn't update with it.

Any nudge in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: The code as it self now seems fine, you need to share code of the TodoItemInList component